# Wordpress display all pages on one page

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I need to display all the pages on the one page.

At the moment I am using this to bring in each page:

```
<?php 
$page_id = 5; //id example
$page_data = get_page( $page_id ); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
$title = $page_data->post_title; 
echo $content; 
?>
```

But if a new page is created it wont display it as wont have this code and its ID in place..

Is there a way to bring all the pages in automatically?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get all the pages of your blog by using `get_pages();`, do this in a loop like so:

```
$pages = get_pages(); 
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
    $title = $page_data->post_title; 
    echo $content; 
}
```

Comment: The returned array doesn't contain any index for "post customs"

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer's returned array doesn't contain "post customs" (which I needed in my case). And also you may need to retrieve pages with specific attributes. Use `args` for more customized results:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => -1,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
?>
```

And use them like this:

```
<?php
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $title = $page->post_title; 
    echo $title. "<br />";
} ?>
```

[Read more here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are using the Twenty Ten theme (I don't know how will it work in others) you can easily get all the pages formatted:

```
echo "<h1 class=\"entry-title\">".$title."</h1>"
    ."<div class=\"entry-content\">".$content."</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get the contents of each page by this code as well.

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Still there is huge problem if you are using custom templates for different pages you can get the content but not the template files on your one page